# Is there a zsh equivalent to the bash `help` builtin?

Tags: zsh

In bash, I can use the `help` command to print a synopsis for a specific builtin command

```bsh
$ help pwd
pwd: pwd [-LP]
    Print the name of the current working directory.

    Options:
      -L    print the value of $PWD if it names the current working
            directory
      -P    print the physical directory, without any symbolic links

    By default, `pwd' behaves as if `-L' were specified.

    Exit Status:
    Returns 0 unless an invalid option is given or the current directory
    cannot be read.
```

Is there an equivalent in zsh, or do I just use `man zshbuiltins`?

Comment: Answered on [so]. See [linux - How can I read documentation about built in zsh commands? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405382/how-can-i-read-documentation-about-built-in-zsh-commands)

Comment: Relevant StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35456287/5178795

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As indicated in [the Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405382/how-can-i-read-documentation-about-built-in-zsh-commands) in [@DavidPostill's comment](https://superuser.com/q/1563825#comment2381170_1563825), put this into `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
unalias run-help
autoload run-help
HELPDIR=/usr/share/zsh/"${ZSH_VERSION}"/help
alias help=run-help
```

If you're on macOS and installed using Homebrew, then you will want to replace the `HELPDIR` line with this:

```bsh
HELPDIR=$(command brew --prefix)/share/zsh/help
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to see what zsh said about : The noop builtin.

Here's a little hack that worked:

```
man zshbuiltins |& awk '/^ *:/,/^$/'
```

I am running the command man zshbuiltins and using an awk range-based regex to print the line that begins with : (possibly with preceeding whitespace) and ends with a blank newline.

Answer (score 0):

Append this in your `~/.zshrc` file

```
function help(){
    bash -c "help $@"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I thought it was obvious from context, but if I'm in zsh I don't want to read bash help, I want zsh help.

Comment: I think this was intended as a joke.